# Eclipse: task tags in javascript blocks inside html files

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, tags, task

Is it possible to enable task tags like `//TODO` and `//FIXME` for html files in Eclipse? I've already checked in Eclipse's settings and there is no "Task Tags" section for HTML files. The issue is that I'm not really using these task tags in the html itself; they're in blocks of javascript inside the html files. It would be nice to somehow capture them even though they reside in an html file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Eclipse is not able to recognize Task Tags for JavaScript embedded in HTML. You can however use HTML comments to add Task Tags around the blocks of JavaScript. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <!-- TODO: Add meta tags and page title here. -->
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <!-- FIXME: There might be a semicolon missing in this code. -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   // TODO: This comment will not be added to Task Tags in Eclipse.
   var i = 0
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Would result in the following descriptions appearing in your Tasks view:

```
TODO: Add meta tags and page title here.
FIXME: There might be a semicolon missing in this code.
```

To enable Task Tags in Eclipse go to **Preferences > General > Editors > Structured Text Editors > Task Tags**.

(*Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Indigo Service Release 1 Build id: 20110916-0149*)

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks for the tip about using HTML comments!

Comment: Is that still true in the current version? Were you in a project that was set up to work with JavaScript?